# Solve $\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2x}+\cdots\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

If

$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2x}+ \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2x} +\cdots\right) \right) = y$$

then what is $x$?

I was thinking of expanding the brackets and trying to notice a pattern but as it effectively goes to infinity. I don't think I can expand it properly, can I?

Comment: Assuming the infinite ($\dots$) stuff makes sense, what can you say about $y-\frac{1}{2x}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an obvious symmetry to this problem. If infinite sum converges then notice that

$$\frac{1}{2x} + \frac{1}{2}\left(y\right) = y$$

Rearranging and solving gives $\frac{1}{x}=y$ and so $x=\frac{1}{y}$.

Comment: This converges for all $x$. Solving the equation $a_{n+1} = (2x)^{-1} + a_n / 2$, we have that $a_n = c \cdot 2^{1-n}-\frac{2^{-n} \left(1-2^n\right)}{x}$ (for some $c$). This converges to $1$ as $n\to\infty$ independent of $c$ or $x$.

Comment: If my sums are correct, $2^{1-n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, so yes, the answer is independent of $c$. Moreover $2^{-n}(1-2^n) \equiv 2^{-n}-1$ and $2^{-n}-1 \to -1$ as $n \to \infty$. It follows that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(c \cdot 2^{1-n} - \frac{2^{-n}(1-2^n)}{x}\right) = c\cdot 0 - \frac{-1}{x} = \frac{1}{x}$$

But that's what I said.

Comment: Agreed, I just wanted to point out that "If infinite sum converges" is really not necessary, since the sum converges for all $x\neq 0$.

Comment: But $a_n$ does not converge to $1$ as $n \to \infty$ independent of $x$. It depends on $x$ because $a_n \to 1/x$.

Comment: Oh, I see it now! My mistake.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** Note that what is inside the outer pair of parenthesis is equal to $y$.

Comment: How did you deduce this?

Comment: @GraphicsMuncher If you look at the left hand side of the equality (which equals $y$), it is equal to what is inside the outer pair of parenthesis. The only difference is that the expression inside the parenthesis is showing less terms, but as both are infinite sums, both are equal.

Answer (score 3):

Expand. The first term is $\frac{1}{2x}$.

The sum of the first two terms is $\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{4x}$.

The sum of the first three terms is $\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{4x}+\frac{1}{8x}$.

And so on.

The sum of the first $n$ terms is 
$$\frac{1}{2x}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right).$$

As $n\to\infty$, the inner sum approaches $2$. So the whole thing approaches $\frac{1}{x}$.

So we are solving the equation $\frac{1}{x}=y$.

Answer (score 2):

Think about how pretty it is to note that $$\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2x}+ \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2x} +\cdots\right) \right) = y$$ implies $$\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2x}+ \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2x} +\cdots\right) \right) = 2y-\frac{1}{x}=y.$$ Now, solve for $y$. Of course, I'm assuming we don't need to care about convergence here at all.

Comment: And if we care about convergence?

Comment: I figure convergence shouldn't be a problem, because when you write that an infinite sum equals $y$, you're saying it equals a number, which means it converges. Unless, of course, you're using some weird notation in which $\infty$ or $-\infty$ could be expressed by $y$.